# Is it possible to call a drupal function in a custom module through javascript?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6

I was checking if it is  possible to call a drupal function in a custom module through ajax.??
I have a custom form and a `validate.js` filethrough which i have done validation.Is it possible to call a drupal function via `ajax`or is there some other methods ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know javascript works at client side & PHP at server side, it is **not** possible to directly call drupal function from javascript.

Definitely, you can achieve this by ajax call. You need to setup page callback in your custom module & there you can mention the function to call on page request.

Example:

```
$items['ajax/validation'] = array(
    'title' => 'Custom validation', 
    'page callback' => 'custom_validation', 
    'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
    'file' => 'validations.inc',
  );
```

As you can see that on calling `www.example.com/ajax/validation` url **`custom_validation`** function will be called.

Hope this will help.